# Visit duration according to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, duration

I wonder how is "Visit Duration" calculated. If it counts split time between clicks on a site.

Because I have a website composed of index only (with some slideshow etc.).

Is GA tool able to calculate real visit duration time or not?

Thanks a lot.

*Sorry for my english if there are mistakes*

**edited:**
Is there some way how to do reload (simulating of pageview) on a background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Google](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1144430):

> Google Analytics determines visit duration by tracking the elapsed time between pageviews. The last page of a visit is not recorded since there is no subsequent pageview.

Also see [Visit Duration, Avg](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1006253)

Comment: Thanks. Is there some way how to do reload (simulating of pageview) on a background?

Comment: @MireSVK also see http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/UUuv8_ktGsQ